# MongoDB import piece of json files in collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a folder containing .json files. Each file looks like this :

```json
{"data":
   [{"status":0,
     "timestamp":...
     },
     {"status":0,
     "timestamp":...
     },{...
    }],
  "otherinfos":"random"
}
```

What I need to do is to import in a collection the content of the data array.
File are about 10Mo, and folder contains thousands of files...
I tried "mongoimport" command, but it inserted the whole object instead of the desired list of element available in the "data" array.
Is there a way to import an array from a json file in mongo ?
Is there an out-of-the-box solution to import multiple files from folder ?

Thank you,

Antoine

PS : I did a small java software to read each file, and import the list of object from the array in mongo but after weeks of computation I would love to hear better solutions.

Edit : 
I would like my mongoDB data to be stored like this, with each status and timestamp as a separate document :

```
{
  "status":0,
  "timestamp":...
},
{
  "status":0,
  "timestamp":...
},
{...
}
```

So I can request on a timestamp and get the status for example. I have a billion entries like that.

Comment: Could you use mongoimport to import the whole lot, and then selectively [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) the fields you don't need?

Comment: My list of values is inside a property. I don't think I can remove the key with $unset and keep the value as a list. If it is possible, i am interested though. In my example, I want to store X objects with status and timestamps property.

Comment: Ah, that is a little more complicated. Could you [edit] your question to show what your goal is i.e. precisely what format the data needs to be in?

Comment: I edited the post with the expected format

Comment: should each object there be a separate document i.e. `{"status" : 0, "timestamp": ... }` as a single document?

Comment: Yes, it's what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as a two-stage process:

1. Use mongoimport to load the data from each json file into a temporary holding collection; this should be fairly quick.
2. Use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to transform the data into discrete documents, saving each one to a new collection with the [$out operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

The aggregation command might look something like this:

```js
db.tempcollection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  { $project: {
    _id: 0, 
    "status" : "$data.status", 
    "timestamp" : "$data.timestamp"
    }
  },
  { $out: "newcollection" }
]);
```

This is likely to be processed fairly quickly, because it can be done by MongoDB itself on the database server; however it may be worth doing some performance testing on a small data sample to find out.